# Show that the set $\{(x,-2x)\mid x \in \mathbb Z\}$ is denumerable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Show that $A = \{(x,-2x)\mid x \in \mathbb Z\}$ is denumerable.

I know that I have to show that a bijection between $A$ and the set of natural numbers (or the set of integers since both are known to be denumerable) exists but I'm not sure what the function would be.

Comment: What about $f:\mathbb Z\to A:n\to(n,-2n)$ ?

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and edit your post accordingly. Otherwise you may find no one interested in answering your question, and it may be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(z)=(z,-2z)$, where $z\in\Bbb{Z}$ works.

Look at a graph of the points in $A$. They all lie on a straight line and every integer is the $x$ coordinate for one of the points.